# Laravel 7 rate limiter is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, throttling, rate-limiting

I am using the laravel 7 and implement rate limit in kernel file

`protected $routeMiddleware = [ 'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class, ]`

i have 3 route file admin, home and user i put in all file group middleware like
`Route::middleware(['throttle:10,1'])->group(function () { .... }`

but it's take randomly like 8, 9,12,13 like not accurate.

Any other things affected the rate limiter?

i made also change in server config file like

`# Rate Limiting Configuration <Location var/www/html/abcd> SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT SetEnv rate-limit 5 SetEnv rate-limit-burst 5 </Location>`

but not taking, why?
please help me...